# LiveCDs occasionally get corrupted filesystems

Tags: linux, ubuntu, livecd

I made some modifications to a custom Ubuntu9.04 LiveCD (unsquash, re-squash, chroot, etc). It seems to work fine, but I noticed the other day things went really bad when a client was booted into it (we have the teamviewer debian package installed on the liveCD). We primarily use it for imaging the attached host's HDD, so it's a pretty intense process on the RAM/IO.

At any rate, the sudoers file was "zero length", so we couldn't use `sudo` at all (we were trying to open a text document after the imaging was completed to check a hash).

I'm curious if this is an error on my part or liveCDs can do this sort of corruption depending on the quality/size of the user's RAM.

Comment: It very much could be - LiveCD's can work by copying the rootfs into a RAM-disk, which can be corrupted.